# How can I make eslint detect rule violations in JSON files?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, eslint, lint

Below you see my .eslintrc file, which contains the rule that needs to be applied to a .json file.

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "jasmine": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "json"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "camelcase": 2
  }
```

**The rule works literally everywhere in the project, except the .json files.**

I have tried to use the "eslint-plugin-json" and couple of other modules, but they simply just don't work.

Please don't give solutions such as "use jsonlint instead, or etc.", the module for linting in the project is eslint.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, JSON files have not valid JavaScript syntax in most cases: outer curly brackets `{}` are parsed as a block with statements and parsing error `Unexpected token :` happens on the first `key: value` pair. So I am not sure if this can be achieved with ESLint (ESLint checks JavaScript per definition).

You can try something like `` echo "(`cat test.json`)" | eslint --stdin `` though.

However, `camelcase` particularly cannot be applied here: ESlint seems to ignore quoted keys and you cannot use unquoted keys in JSON.

Comment: I think rules that eslint is checking can be applied to json too, even maybe with little functionality enhancer, like a plugin. At least some of the rules.

Comment: I've added a not so simple option to the answer with a caveat.

Comment: Not sure if it can help, but spasibo anyway for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

I made an alternative to `eslint-plugin-json` since it didn't work for me and didn't have auto-fixing - [`eslint-plugin-json-format`](https://github.com/Bkucera/eslint-plugin-json-format)

It will also (optionally) sort your package.json for you

```
eslint --ext .json,.js . --fix
```